# ASP.NET MVC Ajax ActionLink ActionName vs AjaxOptions URL difference?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, hyperlink, action

See this simple Razor markup:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Load something", "LoadPartialView", new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "here",
            LoadingElementId = "loading",
            OnBegin = "show_loading",
            OnComplete = "hide_loading",
            Url = "/Home/LoadPartialView2"
        })
```

I notice if I include `LoadPartialView` as a parameter in the `ActionLink` **and** also specify a URL *LoadPartialView2* in `AjaxOptions`, the generated link will invoke the *LoadPartialView2* action. The optional `Url` takes priority:

- If `Url` was removed, then clicking the link will invoke
  `LoadPartialView`.
- If `ActionName` parameter was set to null, vice versa,
  `LoadPartialView2` will be invoked.

When would the URL in `AjaxOptions` be used over `ActionName`?

I noticed if I set `Url` to `http://www.google.co.uk` it doesn't load the page into the `div` tag (`id="here"`).

Thanks!